# How can I exclude files in Gradle's jar.from?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am using the following code to embed some dependencies in my jar:

```
jar {
    from configurations.embed.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
}
```

However, two of my dependencies both contain a `LICENSE.txt`, resulting in a `java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: LICENSE.txt`. exception.

How can I modify the code to exclude both `LICENSE.txt`s from the jar? I tried adding an `exclude "LICENSE.txt"` to `jar`, but that still results in an exception.

Comment: Why not just use `from configurations.embed`? I don't really understand what the `collect()` is doing for you other than making the build harder to understand.

Comment: @PeterLedbrook To include the contents of the jar dependencies (`zipTree(it)`), rather than the jar files themselves (`it`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching some more, I found an answer [here](https://gist.github.com/paulwoods/1142106).

```
jar {
    from(configurations.embed.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }) {
        exclude "LICENSE.txt"
    }
}
```